# Vue: Reasons to use props instead of referencing parent data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In VueJS, I have seen different ways of accessing parent properties from a component. Say I want to use the parent property `items` in my component.

**First way**

The component has a props value bound to a parent property:

*.js*

```
Vue.component("example", {
  template: "<div></div>",
  props: ["myItems"]
});
```

*.html*

```
<example v-bind:my-items="items"></example>
```

**Second Way**

The child component accesses a parent's properties directly, like this:

```
this.$parent.items
```

**Question**

Is there a reason to use the more elaborate first method over the second? Is there an overhead to "duplicating" data like that, vs. accessing it directly when needed?

Comment: Aren't these two different things? In the first case, the parent is sending value downward to child, and in the second case, the child is sending value upward to the parent. It is however not advisable for a child to change its parent's data directly like this. It needs to do so by triggering an $emit event.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking about "sending a value upward to the parent", just accessing the parent property (specifically, created a new computed value based on `this.$parent.items`)

Comment: I see. I thought you were setting the value of `this.$parent.items`. If it's about just getting the value, then I agree with the answer below. Imagine having to debug when children were accessing parent's values right and left without the parent's knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `props` should be mutated in the parent component, according to [the official doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) :

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to understand.
>
> In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. ***This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component***. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console

So in order to update `props` from child component you should use `this.$emit` event and send the new value in order to handle the update in the parent one.

Comment: Yes and that will keep your code clean and maintenable

Comment: Great, thanks. So I if I used the second way, I could directly modify data (`this.$parent.items = [1,2,3]`), making the code less predictable, whereas using props prevents directly changing the parent data?

Comment: you could achieve `this.$parent.items = [1,2,3]` with clean way by using `this.$emit` event