# Is mutating a property of a prop with v-model bad practice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

The [vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) are quite strict in saying that mutating props inside of the component is bad practice. Also there are two cases described, in which a developer may be tempted to break this rule:

- When setting a default value
- When the given prop values should be mutated.

Since I started with vue.js I found myself tempted updating a props property using `v-model`. Seaching the web I found several discussions which included workarounds or use vuex.

My question is: Is updating a property of a prop using `v-model` OK or is BAD because it alters parent state.
Imo I want to alter the parent state, consider this example

A Crud component, that loads a specific "form" component:

```
<template>
    <awesome-form @formSubmit="onFormSubmit" :entity="entity"></awesome-form>
</template>

<script>
import AwesomeForm from 'SomeForm'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      entity: {}
    }
  },
  components: {
    AwesomeForm
  },
  methods: {
    onFormSubmit () {
      axios.post('/backend', this.entity)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The specific form component:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <input type="text" name="username" v-model="entity.username" />
        ...
    </form>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      entity: {
        type: Object
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submit () {
        this.$emit('formSubmit')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This works like intended and makes data binding super easy. But I guess this is considered bad, as it updates parent state. But in the end of the day this is exactly what i want.

Is this really bad and what are the alternatives?

- Having events for each update and single property (super redundant)
- Always use vuex ... (really?)

Comment: please look at this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53549103/8172857) and this [`discussion`](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/the-right-way-to-do-2-way-props/16487/4) in Vue forum

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @BoussadjraBrahim. It seems the linked discussions feature only mutating a prop but not mutating a property of a prop. When having to have events/listeners for each possible property, the code will be huge for little effect (or I do miss the point). Thanks also for the pointer to the [snyc modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) which seems to be related to the problem

Comment: when i was writing my answer i tried [`this`](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/the-right-way-to-do-2-way-props/16487/7) but it didn't work, after that i found that `sync` modifier could fit to your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the best practice in your case is using `.sync` modifier as mentioned in  [`official docs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) :

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('awesome-form', {
  props: ['entity'],
  template: `
  <div>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" v-model="entity.username">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" v-model="entity.email">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>`,

  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$emit('form-submit')
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      entity: {
        username: '',
        email: ''
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onFormSubmit() {
      console.log(this.entity)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <awesome-form @form-submit="onFormSubmit" :entity.sync="entity"></awesome-form>
  <p> {{entity}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. This looks exactly like the solution I was looking for. I'am still curious what exactly happens, when `.sync` is not used. I guess otherwise `entity` in the parent component will not be aware of any updates?

Comment: what do you mean by *I guess otherwise entity in the parent component will not be aware of any updates*?

Comment: Sorry when I was not clear. I meant: The code even works without using the `sync` modifier. I was pondering what is the difference between using and not using `sync`. I guessed it is about informing a prop about a change. I will have to look at this further. But it seems this is as clean as it can get. Thank you again!

Comment: `sync` modifier came in the version 2.3 to solve the problem of two way binding like explained [`here`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) so that's a clean code

Answer (score 2):

> Is updating a property of a prop using v-model OK or is BAD because it alters parent state

Definitely it's bad because form props are passed as `props` on top level parent. So you should see warning from Vue when you try to change value in child even with `v-model`.

So when I see some form component I expect that it requires some value as `v-model` because form is about editing something. This is example-idea of dynamic form based on `v-model`:

```js
Vue.component('awesome-form', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `#awesome-form-template`,
  methods: {
    update(key, val) {
      // we should create new object on each change
      let updatedCopy = Object.assign({}, this.value, { [key]: val });
      this.$emit('input', updatedCopy)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      console.log('value updated: ' + JSON.stringify(val))
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
      text1: '123',
      text2: '345'
    }
  },
  methods: {
      submit() {
         console.log('submitted!');
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>


<div id="app">
  <awesome-form @form-submit="submit" v-model="form"></awesome-form>
</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id='awesome-form-template'>
  <form @submit.prevent="$emit('form-submit')">
     <div v-for="(val, key) in value" :key="key">
          <input 
          type="text" 
          :value="value[key]" 
          @input="update(key, $event.target.value)"
          :name="key">
      </div>
      <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
   </form>
</script>
```

> Having events for each update and single property (super redundant)

But if you will need to add some validation logic which is specific for each input you will have to define event for each update or something like that.

You can also check solution based on `sync` modifier from question comments(@BoussadjraBrahim) with custom mixin [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/daL40n19/), it can be more flexible in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input and the solution to overcome what seems to be a limitation for generic or generated models. In fact I don't see a warning, when updating a property of a prop, as this seems to hard to detect to compile time. Your statement that my attempt is bad practice is very welcome. In my use case I have an Object I give (down) to several components, like a wizard. Each step modify this object in different ways. Since the relations are very clear I felt that a vuex store seems to be too much work for such a common scenario. For now `sync` seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Yes, in this case with passing prop down to childs - `sync` solution probably is more suitable. Vuex allows you to avoid "props-hell" when you have large nesting level of childs and it can be a pain to deliver prop through all levels to some bottom child(this is solution too if you expect that your app will grow with new components). Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. this definitely makes sense. I'am really happy about all the productive and helpful insights.