# How to access a property of the inital app instance, in a .vue component template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vue-loader

I've set up a new Vue app with the vue-cli. I have vue-loader and and vue-route also running in this project.

How do I access a property `events` in the following instance?

Currently, the below code results in the following error: `Property or method "events" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: function(y) {
    return y(App)
  },
    // Data
    data: {
        events: [
            {
                name : 'this',
                price : 2000
            },
            {
                name : 'that',
                price : 3000
            },
            {
                name : 'the-other',
                price : 4000
            },
        ]
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

**./App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">

      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>

    </div>


      <ul>
          <li v-for="event in events">
              <h2>{{ event.name }}</h2>
              <p>{{ event.price }}</p>
          </li>
      </ul>



      <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `events` data exists only in `main.js` but you're using it in `App.vue` which doesn't have access to it.

To render the `events` data you can pass the `events` as `props` to your `App` component.

```
render: function(y) {
  return y(App, {
    props: {
      events: this.events
    }
  });
}
```

And in your `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>

    </div>
      <ul>
          <li v-for="event in events">
              <h2>{{ event.name }}</h2>
              <p>{{ event.price }}</p>
          </li>
      </ul>

      <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    props: ['events']
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yep! Also worked. Is there a preferred way to do this when global access is needed on the initial property? So if I update this anywhere else, all the other views update too.

Comment: @DevLime Citing from the official docs, you can use this for demos or very small apps that have a handful of components. However, using `this.$root` to access the root instance does not scale well to medium or large-scale applications.

Comment: Yes it's not recommended to access the parent data using `this.$root` like i explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549064/vue-reasons-to-use-props-instead-of-referencing-parent-data/53549103#53549103)

Comment: Thanks for that. This is only for a tech demo but it will be carrying the data across multiple components and updating all views accordingly, will this method hold up in that case?

Comment: Tested on my local. Directly manipulating the value of `events` using the `this.$root` seems to work and it updates the other components as well.

Comment: I spent some time stripping back my app and (as I'm sure you are aware!) this is the answer that the official/recommended Vue educational resources are pointing to. Thanks for your help you two :)

I still have a little bit to go before it 'clicks' but appreciate the rapid responses on this question.

Comment: Quick update - Yes. This is totally clicking now. Very much the right way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

what about this.$root.events or create a computed property in your app component and assign that root events there.

Comment: Yep. `this.$root.events` work immediately. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @DevLime it's not recommended to access parent data in this way, please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549064/vue-reasons-to-use-props-instead-of-referencing-parent-data/53549103#53549103

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it as prop and use template property `template:"<App :events='events'/>",` to render the App component as follows :

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
 template:"<App :events='events'/>",
    // Data
    data: {
        events: [
            {
                name : 'this',
                price : 2000
            },
            {
                name : 'that',
                price : 3000
            },
            {
                name : 'the-other',
                price : 4000
            },
        ]
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

in App.vue :

```
 <template>
 ....
</template>
 <script>
  export default {
    props: ['events']
  }
 </script>
```