# VueJS best practices for passing form-data to child and back to parent

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a VueJS project and have parent/child components like this.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <ChildA v-bind="this.postData.someDataA" />
    ...
    <ChildZ v-bind="this.postData.someDataZ"/>
    <button @click="save">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
    import ChildA from './ChildA';
    ...
    import ChildZ from '.ChildZ';
    data() {
    return {
        postData: {
            someDataA: {field1: 'initialValue'}
            someDataB: { // no initial value'}
            ...
        },
    },
    methods: {
        save() {this.$root.db.save(this.postData)}
    }
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="field1" />
    ...
    <input type="text" v-model="field10" />
</template>

<script>
    props: {
        field1:{type: String, default: 'default if not set by parent'},
        ...
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, I want to pass `this.postData` from `Parent.vue` to a function which saves it to a DB. However, the values for `someDataA`, etc.. come from the `Child.vue`.

When I run my code like this, I get the Vue warning:

`Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.`

Now, my question is, what's the best practice to deal with this kind of situation? Do I have to implement a `<ChildA @change="setSomeDataA()" />` to each of the child elements, and `$emit` an event each time a value of the childs props change?

Comment: sometimes i prefer access to parent data from children using `this.$parent`

Comment: however you should not use props as v-model values in childs components

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549064/vue-reasons-to-use-props-instead-of-referencing-parent-data/53549103#53549103)

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo how should I do it instead? if I want to modify `someDataA` in `Child.vue`?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's better to make computed properties instead of using copy of `value` prop.

```
props: {
  value: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({})
  }
},

computed: {
  field1: {
    get() { return this.value.field1 },
    set(field1) { this.$emit('input', {...this.value, field1 })}
  }
}
```

and use it like that

```
<input type="text" v-model="field1" />
```

Comment: ok I spaced it, this is a better way if the prop may change from the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Set up your child to use `v-model` and then `emit` the change. For example:

The parent calls the child using `v-model`

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <ChildA v-model="this.postData.someDataA" />
    ...
    <ChildZ v-model="this.postData.someDataZ"/>
    <button @click="save">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
    import ChildA from './ChildA';
    ...
    import ChildZ from '.ChildZ';
    data() {
    return {
        postData: {
            someDataA: {field1: 'initialValue'}
            someDataB: { // no initial value'}
            ...
        },
    },
    methods: {
        save() {this.$root.db.save(this.postData)}
    }
</script>
```

The child takes the prop `value` and sets an internal variable to `value`. Your input uses the internal variable as it's v-model. Then using `@change` or a watcher to `emit('input', <your internal variable>)`

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
    <input type="text" @change="objChanged" v-model="myObj.field1" />
    ...
    <input type="text" @change="objChanged" v-model="myObj.field10" />
</template>

<script>
    props: {
        value:{type: String, default: 'wont need a default'},
        ...
    },
    data: {
        myObj: {}
    },
    methods: {
        objChanged(){
            this.$emit('input', this.myObj);
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.myObj = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: To simplify things, could I `deep-watch` myObj and emit the event?

Comment: @ad_on_is, yes I mentioned you could use a watcher

Comment: Oh, sorry... didn't see that ;-)

Comment: and what happens if prop changes at parent component?

Comment: @EmīlsGulbis then it changes at the child component? Think of how v-model works, if another component modifies the prop it will update accordingly

Comment: nop, because in this approach you assign your value to this.myObj on `created` hook